# "if" that doesn't work perfectly

Tags: c#, if-statement

What wrong with this code? Either `combobox` is `"Wholesale"` or `"Retail"` the form show the second statement (true, true). If I untick the `checkbox` the `else` works (`true`, `false`). Any idea why?

```
private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox3.Checked == true || comboBox1.SelectedText == "Standalone")
        {

            this.checkBox1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox1.Enabled = false;
            this.checkBox2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox2.Enabled = false;
        }

        if (checkBox3.Checked == true || comboBox1.SelectedText == "Retail")
        {
            this.checkBox1.BackColor = default(Color);
            this.checkBox1.Enabled = true;
            this.checkBox2.BackColor = default(Color);
            this.checkBox2.Enabled = true;
       }
       else
       {
            this.checkBox1.BackColor = default(Color);
            this.checkBox1.Enabled = true;
            this.checkBox2.BackColor = Color.Gray
            this.checkBox2.Enabled = false;
       }
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple `else if` and the usage of `&&` should do the trick:

```
if (checkBox3.Checked == true && comboBox1.SelectedText == "Standalone")
{
    ...
    //If this case is true, the following cases are not going to be checked
}
else if (checkBox3.Checked == true && comboBox1.SelectedText == "Retail")
{
    ...
    //If this case is true, the following cases are not going to be checked
}
else
{
    ...
    //No case before was true
}
```

Note that the usage of an simple `if` behind an `if` is **NOT** the same as the usage of an `else if` behind an `if`.

Also note that your method `checkBox3_CheckedChanged` only gets called after the state of your third `CheckBox` was changed (unless you took the method for other events)

Comment: Just want to add that the `== true` is not needed as `checkbox3.Checked` returns a bool

Comment: It changes nothing now. Just like not taking any command. All the checkbox are true.

Comment: @bolt19 that's not entirely true since some checkbox implementations have three states (true, false, null). in such cases you'll need to use the `== true` to check the state.

Comment: @Yoav as stated here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx  "If the ThreeState property is set to true, the Checked property will return true for either a Checked or IndeterminateCheckState."

Comment: @bolt19 My bad, got mixed with WPF's `IsChecked` property

Comment: Is there another way guys? It does take the condition, practically it does nothing   if (checkBox1.Checked == true && comboBox1.SelectedText=="Standalone")

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Is taking the else condition even if the combo.box1 has standalone and the checkbox is ticked

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *eliminating* all `if` here and operate with *boolean formulas* only.
First, let's get rid of pesky `(checkBox3.Checked == true || comboBox1.SelectedText == "Standalone")`:

```
 bool isRetail = checkBox3.Checked && comboBox1.SelectedText == "Retail";
 bool isStandalone = checkBox3.Checked && comboBox1.SelectedText == "Standalone";
```

Then try to guess when `CheckBox`s should be `Enabled`:

```
 // checkBox2 is enabled if and only if isRetail 
 //TODO: can see, how checkBox2 is unreadable? Change the name into, say "boxIsRetail"
 this.checkBox2.Enabled = isRetail;
 // checkBox2 is enabled if and only if neither isRetail nor isStandalone
 //TODO: can see, how checkBox1 is unreadable? Change the name into, say "boxIsNeither"
 this.checkBox1.Enabled = !(isRetail || isStandalone);
```

Finally, we should update their `Color`s. `CheckBox`'s `Color` depends on `Enabled` only:

```
 this.checkBox1.BackColor = this.checkBox1.Enabled ? default(Color) : Color.Gray;
 this.checkBox2.BackColor = this.checkBox2.Enabled ? default(Color) : Color.Gray;
```

Putting all together we have

```
 private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   bool isRetail = checkBox3.Checked && comboBox1.SelectedText == "Retail";
   bool isStandalone = checkBox3.Checked && comboBox1.SelectedText == "Standalone";

   checkBox2.Enabled = isRetail;
   checkBox1.Enabled = !(isRetail || isStandalone);

   //TODO: these lines are good candidate to be extracted into a method "UpdateColor"
   checkBox1.BackColor = checkBox1.Enabled ? default(Color) : Color.Gray;
   checkBox2.BackColor = checkBox2.Enabled ? default(Color) : Color.Gray;
 }
```

Please, notice, that you can easily add another `bool` variables like `isWholesale`, `isReserved` etc. and implement corresponding logic without roaming among trees of `if`, `else` and `if else`

Comment: I am retrieving a cascades of errors: Error 12 A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods and , Error 7 Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Comment: @Diegoctn: it seems that the method `private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` should have been put with the class, say `Form1`: `public partial class Form1: Form { ... checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {...}...}`